# Convert hex-encoded string to decimal array in python

Tags: python

For example, I want `68656c6c6f`, the hex encoding of the word 'hello', to be converted into `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]`. I need it as a list, not as a continuous integer.

`x=int("68656c6c6f",16)` is apparently not what I'm looking for because it gives me `448378203247` instead, which makes sense. But it's not my solution.

Comment: The question "hexadecimal string to byte array in python" (For which this question got marked as duplicate) does not give the answer I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this:

```
hex_string = "68656c6c6f"

c_list = []

for c in hex_string.decode("hex"):
    c_list.append(ord(c))
```

Comment: Your soluation is more elegant and straightforward.  It should be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`int(s, base=16)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int),

```
s = "68656c6c6f"
x = [int(s[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]

print(x)
# Output
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

---

Or use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) as mentioned by @Liam

```
s = "68656c6c6f"
x = [ord(c) for c in s.decode('hex')]

print(x)
# Output
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Comment: good answer, thank you for mentioning me!